# Como conseguir esse efeito de scroll - ao rolar a página?

Tags: javascript, css, animação

Neste site, ao fazer qualquer movimento de scroll em seu início, ele rola até o final da seção. Gostaria de saber como esse efeito é executado de maneira correta.

http://seunovopontodevista.com.br/

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: A pergunta foi fechada por depender inteiramente de link externo e não ter uma descrição de qual parte do efeito se refere, mas pode ser editada a qualquer momento para trazer para dentro do formato e do [escopo do site](/help/on-topic). Umas dicas que podem ajudar na elaboração do post: [Tour], [Ask] e [Help].

Answer (score 0):

Não é um simples efeito scroll, são diversos efeitos unidos ao efeito, você precisa de criatividade no CSS :).

Aqui é a página que você encontra a aplicação de estilos.

https://github.com/jlmakes/scrollreveal

E aqui a página de um exemplo simples funcionando.

https://scrollrevealjs.org/

Comment: Não me refiro aos efeitos dos quadros que sobem. Apenas ao de scroll do início.

Comment: imagine a mesma estrutura, mas sem os efeitos que existem ali, exceto o de scroll.

Comment: Ok, qual o seu conhecimento em js? gostaria de um exemplo em código ou posso só te passar a lógica a ser aplicada?

Comment: Intermediário. Se conseguir um exemplo, melhor ainda.

Comment: Beleza, quando sair do serviço monto a paginazinha. Basicamente você precisa capturar com js a altura inicial da página. Capture também a altura da div que você quer que o scroll vá. Depois disso compare um com o outro. Chame o evento de scroll do js e crie a condição. Caso a altura da página seja menor que a altura onde a div se encontra, ir direto para a div a ser apresentada.

Answer (score 0):

Fazer esse processo é custoso pois envolve pegar a posição da rolagem usando javascript e assim executar animações com css, porem existe um plugin que pode lhe ajudar muito nisso que é o scrollmagic, na pagina a seguir você vera um exemplo e toda a documentação para utilização do mesmo.

http://scrollmagic.io/

Documentação:
http://scrollmagic.io/docs/index.html

Para que o scroll inicial em que o conteudo rola, porem o menu lateral fica parado, você pode fixar o menu usando a propriedade position:fixed do css
Segue exemplo:
CSS:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box;}
body { margin: 0;}
.menu { width: 20vw; left: 0; top: 0; height: 100vh; background: #EEE;position: fixed; z-index: 2}  
.bg { background:url('http://likefotos.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/paisagem-tailandia1.jpg'); width: 100vw; height: 100vh; background-size: 100% auto; left: 0; top: 0; position: fixed; z-index: 1;}
.content { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 100%; width: 100vw; height: 100%; background: #FFF; z-index: 3;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="menu"></div>
<div class="bg"></div>
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum</div>
```